# numpy.int rounds to wrong value

Tags: numpy, dtype

after updating numpy, numpy.int gives deprecation warnings, so I tried to convert all variables in code to int8 (many of the variables are arrays of 1 and 0).
Can someone explain the results from a simple tryout below?

```
Out[8]: 150.0

np.int8(300/2)
Out[9]: -106

np.int16(300/2)
Out[10]: 150

np.int32(300/2)
Out[11]: 150
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The smallest signed number that can be represented in 8 bits is -128 and the largest is 127.[numpy doc](https://numpy.org/doc/1.20/user/basics.types.html) You can learn more about this [here].[2](http://users.ece.utexas.edu/%7Evalvano/embed/chap3/chap3.htm) and [here](https://www.educative.io/edpresso/how-to-represent-negative-binary-numbers).

Comment: funny i did not pay attention to negative numbers, thanx!